# Converting string to int in DatagramSocket server

Tags: java, datagram, numberformatexception

I am using the code found on [this site](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/) to create a UDP client and server. My code was working up until now and now I cannot convert the string, sent from the client to the server, into an integer.

The problem I'm getting is a NumberFormatException on line 57 in the udpServer java file.

Here is the output of the error:

```
Starting game...
Client connection established! Game started

Button 10 turned on
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ie.dit.student.briscoe.brian.udpServer.run(udpServer.java:57)
```

Here is the server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.util.Random;

class udpServer extends Thread
{
   private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
   int score;

   /* Declaring the constructor for this class */
   public udpServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      /* This line creates a new server socket and uses the 
       * port number variable as the parameter */
      serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      /* This line sets the timeout for the server to 10 seconds.
       * This means that the server will wait for connections for 
       * 10 seconds and close if no connections are received in that
       * time*/
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting game...");
      System.out.println("Client connection established! Game started");
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      int buttonInt, randInt;
      Random rand;
      String sentence, capitalizedSentence;

         while(true)
         {
            try 
            {
               rand = new Random();
               randInt = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);  
               System.out.println("\nButton " + randInt + " turned on");

               DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
               serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
               sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());

/*line 57*/    buttonInt = Integer.parseInt(sentence);

               if(buttonInt == randInt)
               {
                    System.out.println("Player pressed the correct button");
                    score += 1;
               }// End

               else
               {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect button pressed\nGame over!");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                    break;
               }// End else

               //System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
               InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
               int port = receivePacket.getPort();
               capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
               sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
               DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
               serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }// End try

            catch (SocketTimeoutException s)
            {   
                /* Informing the user of the error that happened */
                System.out.println("Time up\nGame over!");
                //System.out.println("Score = " + score);

                /* Exiting the program */
                break;
            }// End catch

            catch (IOException i)
            {
               i.printStackTrace();
            }// End catch
         }
   }

   /*The start of the main loop */
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      /* This line creates and initialises a variable to store the port number used
       * for the connection */
      int port = 4444;
      try
      {
         /* This line creates a new thread which is an instance of this class
          * with the port number supplied by the user as an argument as the port
          * number for the server */
         Thread t = new udpServer(port);

         /* Start the thread */
         t.start();

      }// End try

      /* This will be satisfied if some sort of input/output error has occurred */
      catch(IOException e)
      {  

         e.printStackTrace();
      }// End catch
   }// End main()
}
```

Here is the client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class udpClient
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     String serverName = "localhost";
     int port = 4444;
     while(true)
     {
        try
        {
           DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
           BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           Console console = System.console();

           String userStr = console.readLine("Read the server window to see which button to press: ");

           if(userStr != null)
           {
              try
              {
                 int temp = Integer.parseInt(userStr);

                 if(temp > 0 && temp < 13)
                 {
                    System.out.println("You pressed button " + userStr);
                    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                    //String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                    sendData = userStr.getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                    System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
                    clientSocket.close();  
                 }// End if

                 else
                 {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input value not in range\nGame over");
                    clientSocket.close();
                 }// End else
              }// End try

              catch(NumberFormatException n)
              {
                 System.out.println("Invalid input\nGame over");
                 clientSocket.close();
              }// End catch
           }// End if

           else
           {
              System.out.println("Invalid input userstr = null\nGame over");
              clientSocket.close();
           }

           /* Closing the socket client connection */
           clientSocket.close();

        }// End try

        catch(IOException e)
        {
           /* This will print the technical specification of the error that has
            * occurred */
           e.printStackTrace();
           break;
        }// End catch
     }// End infinite while loop
  }// End main()
}// End class udpClient
```

Here is the output of the new issue:

```
Starting game...
Client connection established! Game started

Button 1 turned on
Player pressed button 1
strlength pre trim = 1024
strlen post trim = 1
Correct!

Button 12 turned on
Player pressed button 12
strlength pre trim = 1024
strlen post trim = 2
Correct!

Button 1 turned on
Player pressed button 12
strlength pre trim = 1024
strlen post trim = 2
Incorrect!
Game over!
Score: 2 points
```

The third iteration is where the problem lies. The client sent "1" to the server yet it was read as "12"

Comment: Is the input string really ``"10"``? I do not understand the exception if so.

Comment: My guess is that there are unprintable characters in there as well. Try logging the length of the string first...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The string length is 1024 pre-trim. It works fine when the number sent by the client. However when the number is a single digit, the last digit from the previous number is concatenated to the end. Here is the output Button 10 turned on
Player pressed button 10
strlength = 1024
Correct!

Button 7 turned on
Player pressed button 70
strlength = 1024
Incorrect!

Comment: I have updated my original post to contain the output in a more readable format. I would appreciate it if you could view it to give some insight into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you trim any excess whitespace on your sentence variable prior to parsing it.

```
buttonInt = Integer.parseInt(sentence.trim());
```

From your exception, it looks like there's no whitespace - but it could be a non-printable character sneaking into your string.

Comment: Thanks this helped my issue! However there is still a small problem. Whenever a single digit is sent from client to server, the last character of the previous number string is added to the single digit string, ending the game. Here is example output:  Button 10 turned on Player pressed button 10 strlength = 1024 Correct! Button 7 turned on Player pressed button 70 strlength = 1024 Incorrect!

Comment: I have updated my original post to contain the output in a more readable format. I would appreciate it if you could view it to give some insight into my problem.